# URLSessionWebSocket Not Calling didClose Delegate Method

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, urlsession

I'm trying to use `URLSessionWebSocket` to establish a web socket connection. I have the following code to make that happen:

```swift
class WebSocketManager: NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    private var urlSession: URLSession!
    var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask?

    func run() {
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let url = URL(string: "ws://127.0.0.1:3000")!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
        webSocketTask!.resume()
    }

    func send() {
        webSocketTask!.send(URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string("Hello from Client"), completionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error sending message: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Sent message")
            }
        })
    }

    func receive() {
        webSocketTask?.receive(completionHandler: { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error receiving message: \(error)")
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case .string(let text):
                    print("Received: \(text)")
                case .data(let data):
                    print("Received binary message: \(data)")
                @unknown default:
                    fatalError()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("didCompleteWithError")
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
        print("didBecomeInvalidWithError")
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        print("Did close with")
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        print("didOpenWithProtocol")
    }
}
```

Then I'm using `wscat --listen 3000 --slash` in my command line to test a web socket server to test with.

When I run the application, I can send messages, and receive messages after calling the relevant methods. That all works fine.

However, when I hit `Command + C` to exit the web server, it never lets the client application know. The delegate methods don't get called when that occurs. So the client has no way of knowing when the connection has been terminated.

How can I fix this and get alerted when the web socket is disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to call `receive`. If you call `receive`, then the web socket is closed/disconnected, it will call your delegate methods.

This applies if you call `receive` before or after the socket is closed/disconnected.

But if the socket is closed/disconnected and you never call `receive`, you won't ever receive those delegate methods.